# DateTime value has additional hour after insert

Tags: sql-server-2012, datetime

I developed a Windows Service (with a fixed culture of "de-DE") in C#. This service is getting data from an API and copies it over to a Navision Database.

My problem is following: After I've copied the data, every DateTime value got an additional hour. So if the DateTime value from API was 13:25:00, in the Navision database it is now 14:25:00.

When retrieving the DateTime value from API it is of kind "Unspecified".

To insert it into the Navision database I'm doing a simple
`INSERT INTO [TABLE] (..., [Date_Time], ...) VALUES (..., [DATETIME VALUE], ...)`.

This just happens on customer side. In my test environment I can confirm that the same DateTime value from the source is inserted into the database.

I used the Database Creation Script provided by the customer to create the database in my test environment.

I cannot see all sources of failure, because I'm not yet so deep into this.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone mismatch.  How did you copy the data?   What was the datatype?

Comment: @JonathanFite When retrieving the DateTime value it is of .NET DateTime type. And to copy it to the Navision database, I'm doing a simple INSERT INTO. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Does the Navision application display the adjusted time, or are you seeing the adjusted time when you query the table through SSMS?

Comment: The customer reported me back that he sees the adjusted time in the Navision application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application issue more than a database issue.

Navision [treats datetime entries as UTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355274.aspx), and is adding the hour in its display (assuming your local timezone is UTC+1).

I have run into this myself since I work with Navision. If you have a client application, you can look at displayed datetime for a record and compare it to what you see by querying the table.

Comment: So your answer is correct and gave the best direction to find the problem. But the problem was more on customer side. My service replaces a script which transfers data. The script the administrator created six years ago was using the wrong datetime format since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the time zones on your Servers - and on the customer computers, if you can. One of them is probably an hour off.

Comment: I did. They‘re all „german“.

Answer (score 0):

Never use string type to communicate dates with other systems. Use UNIX timestamps with a wrapper class around them, for example in C# System.DateTime. The drivers know how to serialize/convert this value back and forth properly. If you still have to use strings, consider a standard format such as  [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Represent a date fully, such as 2017-12-19T15:25:23+01:00. This way, you provide the timestamp and the desired representation (GMT+1). The desired representation may be discarded by the database server. Apply the same upon retrieving the timestamp.

Comment: I do use the SqlParameter class in .NET to use the DateTime object. Didn‘t mentioned it here, because I think the problem rather lays in a misconfiguration than in wrong data.

Comment: what about reading? do you read the parameter with SqlDataReader.GetDateTime?

Comment: There is no need of reading the data. I just copy it over. Unit and integration tests verify the data for correctness.